# rails 3, how can I send an object name through a form_for and create a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I think this is simple but I haven't figured it out yet.

I have a super simple form_for:
    <%= form_for @redemption do |f|  %>

```
       <%= f.text_field :code  %> 
        <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
       <% end %>
```

a User enters a code and that is sent to the redemptions#create action

```
def create
     @code = Code.find_by_id('6')
     @redemption = @code.redemptions.find_or_create_by_code_id_and_user_id(@code.id, current_user.id) 
      if @redemption.save
        redirect_to bands_url, :notice => "Redemption Successful."
      else
        redirect_to bands_url, :notice  => "Could not redeem code"
      end
  end
```

this code works but not at all for production (obviously) due to hard coding an ID in there.

The piece I don't get is: How to send a Code.code through the form and somehow get that code's.id.  I know how to pass it into a Redemption...

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form will pass `params`. You mention "How to send a Code.code"  does that mean your `redemption[:code]` is the same as this Code.code where you get the Code.id from?  (the 6 in  your example).

If it's the same use something like

```
def create
  @code = Code.find_by_code(params[:redemption][:code]) # just to show you how to use it
  @redemption = @code.redemptions.find_or_create_by_user_id(current_user.id) # that part looked redundant but i don't know what you're trying to do.
  if @redemption.save
    redirect_to bands_url, :notice => "Redemption Successful."
  else
    redirect_to bands_url, :notice  => "Could not redeem code"
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks, still a newb at Rails so sometimes I forget whats happening. One interesting note: if I try to redeem the same code twice it gets to the Redemption Successful notice, but only 1 redemption is credited, which I want, but don't know why it works that way

Comment: It works that way because you are either finding or creating by a user Id and i guess save is being set to true regardless. maybe... good catch. For now at least it's only saving one real DB record. small wins :-)